# vs code not selecting the right python interpreter

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, ssh

I have been using vs code and its data science module for a long time to create and edit python scripts via SSH. Recently I tried to open a jupyter notebook with it but I am having issues with the python interpreter

The python interpreter selected is the one from the `base` environment from miniconda

[image]

However, when I try to import a module that is installed on conda `base` I am getting

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-094d2d97d2ef> in <module>
      1 # imports
      2 import pandas as pd
----> 3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I am sure that `matplotlib` is installed on the `base` environment. If, on a terminal window, on VS code itself, I

1. open the same python interpreter (`/home/user/miniconda3/bin/python`)
2. call the same import (`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`)

I get no error:

```
(base) user@Brightcore-testsrv:~$ which python
/home/user/miniconda3/bin/python
(base) user@Brightcore-testsrv:~$ /home/user/miniconda3/bin/python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VS Code Jupyter notebook may be running with a different interpreter as its kernel. You can execute this code to check:

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

If the result of running the code above is not `/home/user/miniconda3/bin/python`, you can use the kernel selector to switch kernels to your desired environment.